# how to remove logo of log on page of ADFS 3.0 using powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, adfs

I trying to change logo of log on page of ADFS 3.0 using powershell. I am able to set using command but not able to remove .
Can anybody know how to remove that logo using powershell command.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following PowerShell command to remove custom logo from default theme:

```
Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName default -Logo @{}
```

If yon need to remove the customized illustration you can use this command:

```
Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName default -Illustration @{}
```

Comment: In the case of the illustration, this actually _clears_ the illustration, which leaves you with a solid color, not the default image.  For most people, that's probably sufficient.

Comment: @MikeBaz-MSFT how can we add default illustration back?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way.  Out of the box it's set to a byte array.  I suppose you could do a clean install somewhere, do a `(Get-AdfsWebTheme).Illustration` to get the bytes, and put those somewhere into a file, then put that over to the other environment, but I haven't fully tested that and don't really know what the official supported answer is.